# Struggling with Limited Query-Making Abilities in Hasura's Instant API: Seeking Better LCNC Tool Suggestions

Tags: database, api, graphql, hasura, lowcode

so I'm a startup and I'm using low-code-no-code tools like Hasura to create an instance API from my database.

The problem is that while Hasura gives me an instant API, I don't have the flexibility to create various types of queries, like using different aggregation functions or joining multiple tables.
Basically, I can't manipulate the data and expose more complex queries. So, I'm looking for another LCNC tool that can provide a more usable instance API with better query-making abilities than Hasura. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can create views for the complex queries that you need and expose them on Hasura.